# Heroku: How expensive could running my application be?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, server

I'm about to release an iOS app, and deploy its backend (rails backend that serves the iOS app) to heroku.

I have very little knowledge when it comes to the practical price you will pay based on traffic, etc. This link (http://notes.ericjiang.com/posts/881) states... *Nowadays, especially with faster code and faster computers, a standard 512MB dyno can power websites with tens of thousands of hits per hour.*

I'm trying to get a rough estimate of how much running my backend on heroku could cost me. What's the best way to figure this out? The pricing is all very straightforward. It basically just comes down to how many dyno's I'm going to need.

If I get 5 beta testers to run my iOS app for a 10 minute window, can I extrapolate some statistics as to how much my backend is being used? Is it the 'hits' that matter, or the 'data' transferred, or the 'time' the backend is actively doing something, like queueing up some resulting data?

Is there a formula to figure it out?  Let's say say a user averages 10 hits per minute, and I constantly have an average of 5000 users. That would be 3 million hits per hour. What exactly should I be looking for in trying to determine an accurate pricing for my first backend?

Answer (score 2):

While Heroku do have [some limits](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits) surrounding bandwidth (not requests) for the most part your cost is close to fixed.

Monthly pricing is typically made up from a combination of:

- Dynos
- Databases
- Addons
- Premium support

Heroku provide [a price calculator](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) on their website. Further, standard (non-hobby) dynos and up include metrics around CPU usage and memory usage.

My suggestion if you're just starting out? Start with one web dyno and a Postgres database. Beta test your app and check your metrics. A Rails app on a single Standard 1X dyno can handle a reasonable amount of traffic (depending on what else it might be doing) and if you need to add more dynos it's only a command line interface away.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. To check metrics do I need to spin up 2 dynos at once? When I login to Heroku Dashboard > Metrics I am told "Application Metrics are currently only available for apps with two or more running dynos of any size."

Comment: You need at least one Standard 1X dyno to see metrics.